# Install a module in Linux

Tags: 7

I am looking to download and install a module using the Linux command line.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You can install Drush (see [Installing Drush on Ubuntu](http://groups.drupal.org/node/23487) or [How to install Drush server-wide in less than one minute](http://openspring.net/tip/how-to-install-drush-serverwide-in-less-than-one-minute)); after, you can install a module with drush:

  - to download a module

    ```
    drush dl modulename
    ```
  - to enable the module

    ```
    drush en modulename
    ```
- Also, you can use wget to download the module, and make a directory inside the modules directory (in this case the modules directory is /home/youruser/public_html/sites/all/modules/).

```csh
    wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/modulename-6.x.tar.gz
    mkdir -p /home/youruser/public_html/sites/all/modules/modulename
    tar -zxf modulename-6.x.tar.gz -C /home/youruser/public_html/sites/all/modules/modulename
```

Enable the  module in "Administer > Site building > Modules."

Comment: I liked that you provided both the options with and without drush.

Answer (score 6):

To install Drupal modules using command line, you have to install `Drush Composer` on your machine.

So use this link to install Drush using composer : https://github.com/drush-ops/drush

After installing it, open your terminal and go to your project/drupal directory into which you want to download modules.

To download and enable modules using a single command, run following command:

```
drush en -y your_module_name
```

Note : your_module_name should be the name present on the url of the module name like `https://www.drupal.org/project/your_module_name`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is via the [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) project.  This will allow you to download and enable modules via the command line similar to the code below.

```
# Download the Views module
drush dl views

# Enable the Views module
drush en views
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have (or don't want) drush, you can also just do something like this:

```
$ cd $MY_DRUPAL_SITE_ROOT/sites/all/modules
$ wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/querypath-6.x-1.6.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf querypath-6.x-1.6.tar.gz
```

(the -z flag to the tar command does a "gunzip" of the file before untarring)

From there, you can go to the Site Building -> Modules screen and install the module there.

That said, if you are going to be doing this a lot, Drush is very helpful

Comment: Or you can even combine both commands together  wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/querypath-6.x-1.6.tar.gz && 
 tar -zxvf *.tar.gz

Comment: What would be the next step to configure these modules?

Answer (score 1):

Install drush, which is a command line tool for Drupal. Downloading and installing a module would just need you to execute two commands. (The first command download the module, and the other one installs it.)

```
drush dl <modulename> 
drush en <modulename> -y
```

These commands will take care of module dependencies too.

Comment: @ arpitr -thanks for your response,already my drupal 7 is running .again i want to install drush?

Comment: drush is independent. After installation you just need to run drush commands inside drupal installation directory, there are other cool stuff you can do with drush http://drushcommands.com/drush-7x

Answer (score 0):

1-   By using cyber duck tool we can import any thing into linux server from windows.using ip,username,password,port.
http://www.v3.co.uk/v3-uk/download-review/2032496/cyberduck-windows-v401

2-   wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/modulename-7.x-1.0-rc2.tar.gz

```
 mkdir -p /home/force_password_change-7.x-1.0-rc2.tar.gz -C /home/www/html/transgenic/sites/all/modules/modulenmae
```

procedure
-open terminal  and give the download link adrress(above format) it will download save on desktop and follow second command and you can able to see your module,in modules.